# Handler + SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня возникла проблема при вызове setAdapter из Handler-а. В информации об Handler сказано что он работает с потоками, ссылаясь на главный в котором вызван. Я вызвал его в главном потоке, чего он ломается при присвоение адаптера?
Код:

```
    dbHelper = new myDBHelper(this);
    b = new Bundle();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Parser parser = new Parser();
            parser.xmlPars();
        }

    });
    t.start();

   h = new Handler() {
                    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                        dbHelper.open();
                        b = msg.getData(); //msg - из парсера
                        test = b.getString("key");
                        test2 = b.getString("key2");
                        dbHelper.add(test, test2);
                        dbHelper.close();
                        upLoad();
                    };
                };

public void upLoad(){
    dbHelper.open();
    c = dbHelper.getAll();
    c.moveToLast();
    String[] from = {dbHelper.COLUMN_TXT, dbHelper.COLUMN_URL};
    int[] to = {R.id.t_txt, R.id.t_url};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.t_items, c, from, to);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.t_ListView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    dbHelper.close();

    }
```

Можно ли попросить или заставить дядьку Handler, ссылатся на главный поток при вызове upLoad()?
Или как мне еще заставить курсор следить за нововведениями в DB, не дожидаясь окончания парсинга в Handler.

Comment: ничего хорошего о предоставленном куске кода сказать нимогу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) и не парься по поводу потоков.

Comment: А есть способ, что бы именно с Handlera сослаться на главный поток? Но не очередным потоком типа MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread, а еще одной простой задачей.